# How to close or disable a list

Tags: list

I have a list that was used for employees to "sign-up" to bring an item to an office function.  Is there a proper way to close or disable employees from posting to the list?  I am looking to remove this function later today.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to **List Settings page** then **Advance Settings.** On this page you Under the **Item-Level Permissions** You will see the **Create and Edit Access**

Over here you select None, thats mean no body can **add/ edit the items.**
Like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To block additional signups, you have 2 options.

You go into the list permissions and set anyone with contribute or edit permission to Read. If your list is inheriting permission from the parent, then you need to break permission inheritance and set them to read access.

You remove everyone's permission. In the same way as above, instead of setting them to read, you delete their permission instead.

The advantage of option 1 is users can still see the data, but can't intteract with it, so there might be some confusion. Option 2 removes their access completely.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clear cut options with this.